# How to prevent ios prompt (Cancel and OK button present) while one app opening from any browser

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, iphone

I am submitting one virtual form at browser which actually opens installed app at mobile . But in iPhone, I am getting one prompt message showing "This will open in different app- Cancel / Ok". If user click on the Ok it will open the installed app. My questions are as follows -

1. Can we skip this prompt dialog and opens installed app directly with javascript.
2. Can we get any js event while user click on the cancel button at prompt dialog.

Comment: Check for iOS universal link, you are probably using URL scheme and it will always ask to open app.

Comment: can you please explain how ios universal link works . is there any live example